# Changing Spring RequestMapping annotation value at runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-annotations

I am trying to change the value of the RequestMapping annotation at runtime for a HTTP GET method - **hello** (which returns a simple string) inside a rest service class - **SpringRestController**.

The value of the uri defined in the @RequestMapping annotation on the hello method is **"/hello/{name}"**. I am able to change the value of the annotation at runtime to **"hi/{name}"** using reflection in the constructor of the SpringRestController class.

I am able to verify the modified value by printing the value of the annotation inside an init method annotated with @PostConstruct annotation and also inside another controller. However, when I am trying to access the  GET method in a browser: 
 
with the modified value - *http://localhost:9090/spring-boot-rest/rest/hi/Pradeep*  (**does not work**)

with the original value - *http://localhost:9090/spring-boot-rest/rest/hello/Pradeep*  (**works fine**)

I expect the HTTP GET method hello to be accessible using the modified path value at runtime - **"/hi/{name}"** instead of the original path value - **"/hello/{name}"**. 
P.S - This is a requirement for us and needs to be done this way so that value of @RequestMapping can be configured externally without changes to the source code.

 
Here is the code - SpringRestController.java

```
package com.example.spring.rest.controller;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.example.spring.rest.custom.annotations.ConfigurableRequestMapping;
import com.example.spring.rest.reflection.ReflectionUtils;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class SpringRestController {

    public SpringRestController() {
            RequestMapping rm = SpringRestController.class.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
            System.out.println("Old annotation : " + rm.value()[0]);
            RequestMapping rmNew = new ConfigurableRequestMapping("/rest");
            ReflectionUtils.alterAnnotationValueJDK8_v2(SpringRestController.class, RequestMapping.class, rmNew);
            RequestMapping rmModified = SpringRestController.class.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
            System.out.println("Constructor -> New annotation : " + rmModified.value()[0]);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello/{name}")
    public String hello(@PathVariable String name) {
        System.out.println("Name : " + name);
        return "Hello " + name;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        System.out.println("Annotations initialization post construct.");
        RequestMapping rmModified = SpringRestController.class.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
        System.out.println("Init method -> New annotation : " + rmModified.value()[0]);
    }
}
```

Code for changing annotation value -

ReflectionUtils.java

```
package com.example.spring.rest.reflection;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import com.example.spring.rest.controller.SpringRestController;
import com.example.spring.rest.custom.annotations.ConfigurableRequestMapping;
import com.example.spring.rest.utils.PropertyReader;

public class ReflectionUtils {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static Object changeAnnotationValue(Annotation annotation, String key, Object newValue){
        Object handler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(annotation);
        Field f;
        try {
            f = handler.getClass().getDeclaredField("memberValues");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Map<String, Object> memberValues;
        try {
            memberValues = (Map<String, Object>) f.get(handler);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        Object oldValue = memberValues.get(key);
        if (oldValue == null || oldValue.getClass() != newValue.getClass()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        memberValues.put(key,newValue);
        return oldValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this would be possible because at the application start spring will get the value of the annotation and stores it. You would need to change the cached value inside spring.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to change the annotation value in runtime since Spring already registered that value. Aside from being curious about what do you really try to achieve, feel free to use multiple `@PathVariable` parameters, and handle the evaluation yourself.

```
// Either hardcoded values or loaded from elsewhere
private static List<String> GREETINGS = Arrays.asList("Hello", "Hi");

...

@GetMapping(value = "/{greeting}/{name}")
public String greeting(@PathVariable String greeting, @PathVariable String name) {
    System.out.println("Name : " + name);
    if (GREETINGS.stream().anyMatch(greeting::equalsIgnoreCase)) {
        return greeting + " " + name;
    }
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, 
        "Unknown greeting " + greeting, e);
}
```

Moreover, the point of the REST API endpoints is to be *predictable*. What you try to achieve seems like a contradiction to it. You can have multiple endpoints such as `/hi/{name}` and `/hello/{name}`, however, in this particular case either the usage of multiple parameters is correct, or this following endpoint that respects the *resource* and uses `@RequestParam`. I'd design it rather with this way since *greeting* is the resource.

- A sample endpoint: `/greeting?greeting={greeting}&name={name}`
- A sample call: `/greeting?greeting=Hello&name=Pradeep%20Prabhakaran`

Comment: Hi @Nikolas, thanks for answering, but as I said in my post I am able to see the changed value of the annotation in the init method of SpringRestController class. the init method is annotated with PostConstruct so it will be called once the dependencies are  injected . The purpose is to change the path value externally from a configuration instead of changing it in the code directly. I know this sounds confusing but this is what is expected as per the requirement.

Comment: Yes, but Spring works with the old value. The only way is to change the cached value in Spring. And I am not sure if it is a good idea, actually, it looks like a design smell, a lot. That's why I offered you alternatives through my answer.

Comment: I know this sounds a dirty approach, but is there an option to reload the bean after changing the annotation value?

Comment: I haven't heard of/found any way to do that. You have to wait for another answer.